# Make \emph{} look like Stackoverflow highlighting

Tags: emphasis

How can I make `\emph{}` look exaclty like `this` StackExchange highlighting.

I like the highlighting from StackExchange forum family and would like to use it in my Latex document.

Sorry I can't put my question into words, so I can't google it myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to redefine the `\emph` command, and you will need the `color` package to provide you with a shaded box.  Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.85}
\renewcommand\emph[1]{\colorbox{light-gray}{\texttt{#1}}}
\begin{document}

This is some \emph{marked} text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, there's a smarter way to do this that let's you use back ticks in the same way as SE does, using the `newverbs` and `shortvrb` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.85}
\usepackage{newverbs}
\usepackage{shortvrb}
\newverbcommand{\cverb}
{\setbox\verbbox\hbox\bgroup}
{\egroup\colorbox{light-gray}{\box\verbbox}}
\MakeSpecialShortVerb{\cverb}{\`}
%
\begin{document}

This is some `quoted` text, that allows `\TeX` macros to be shown without expansion.

\end{document}
```

[image]

But don't do this if you want to use the back tick for the left hand typographical quotation mark as Knuth originally intended in plain TeX.

And (as pointed out in the comments) putting things into a box like this prevents line breaks inside the box, so this approach is only suitable for short pieces of text, and you should be prepared to rewrite to avoid over- or under-full lines.

Comment: As far as I know, `xcolor` is preferred over `color` and is (at least largely) backwards compatible.

Comment: `xcolor` would work just as well, but `color` is smaller, simpler, and not-yet-obsolete.  Without more context or a MWE from the OP it's hard to tell which to prefer, so I went for simplicity.

Comment: @Thruston This won't allow line breaks.

Comment: Thank You. The first solution with redefening `\emph` works fine for me. The second solution does not work. I suppose the problem is that I use XeLaTeX or maybe that I use `\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}`
`\MakeOuterQuote{"}`

Comment: To allow line breaks in highlighted text you can use the `soul` package.

Comment: why is it so thick?

Comment: @kww It looks like it does, because that's how the Computer Modern Typewriter font was designed.  You might prefer a different type writer font, or you could change the background colour - a lighter colour might make the font look less dense.

Comment: @Thruston Thanks. Is there any way now to look exactly like stackexchange's.